# apt-get install выдает Can't exec "insserv"

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Пробую поставить любой пакет через `sudo apt-get install` Все скачалось, поставилось но не до конца. Вот логи

```
Настраивается пакет ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ (0.0.0-0) …
Can't exec "insserv": Нет такого файла или каталога at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 406.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 255
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Была похожая ошибка. В скрипте `ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ.postinst` возникает ошибка.
Нужно вручную отредактировать скрипт. Он находится в `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.
Проще всего закомментировать команду `set -e` и в конец добавить `exit 0`.

Answer (score 0):

для начала

> apt-get -f install

а ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ: что за программа если не секрет? возможно дело в репозиториях (репозитории). и какая Ubuntu?

Comment: нет не вышло совсем

Comment: apt-get -f install
не установлено до конца или удалено 1 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Настраивается пакет ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ (0.0.0-0) …
Can't exec "insserv": Нет такого файла или каталога at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 406.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 255
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Так с любой программой, с репозиториями все нормально, обновления получаю, установить не могу до конца

Comment: а если **apt-get purge ИМЯ_ПРОГРАММЫ**, затем **apt-get -f** ?

Comment: **Can't exec "insserv": Нет такого файла или каталога at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 406. update-rc.d** говорит о том что в исполняемом файле-сценарии **/usr/sbin/update-rc.d** в строке **406** вызывается **insserv** которого не существует...
попробуйте
**apt-get install insserv**, затем **apt-get update** затем **apt-get install ИМЯ_ПРОГАММЫ**.

Comment: Нет не помогло, apt-get install insserv пишет что уже установлен, и дальше тажа история

Comment: попробуйте сделать копию файла **/usr/sbin/update-rc.d**, затем удалить или закомментировать 406-ю строку в файле **/usr/sbin/update-rc.d**... а что содержит 406-я строка в файле **/usr/sbin/update-rc.d**?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33788/discussion-between--and--).